# index for name input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<input type="text" name="test[ooo][]">
<input type="text" name="test[bbb][]">
<input type="text" name="test[ccc][]">
<input type="text" name="test[vvv][]">
​
$('input').each(function(){
  console.log($(this).attr('name').index('bbb'));
})​
```

Why this not working? How can i check index for attribute name from input?

http://jsfiddle.net/UA2BN/

I don't must use index(). I can use other function, but how can i check this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for `indexOf`.

console.log($(this).attr('name').indexOf('bbb'));

> -1
>
> 5
>
> -1
>
> -1

http://jsfiddle.net/5uVd9/

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't work because the jQuery selects all for input elements, and loop through them, interpreting the names as name-strings. In jQuery's mind this are not arrays at all.

Off course you can always select a specific input by selecting a substring in its name:

```
console.log( $('input[name*="[bbb]"]') );​
```

this will select an `input` with it's name containing the substring `[bbb]`.

Answer (score 1):

try this code:

```
inputs= document.getElementsByTagName("input");
for(i=0;i<inputs.length;i++)
   alert(i);​
```